# trying to approximate e using while loops in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, equation

I'm supposed to approximate the value of e by using 1 + 1/1 + 1/2 +1/3 and so on, up to the amount that the user entered (like 10 would be up to one tenth) i have most of it figured out but cant get the right output   here's what I've got

```
def iterationE(e):
    count = 0
    num = 1
    while count <= e:
        count = count + 1
        num = 1 + 1/count
    return num
e = int(input ("enter the number of iterations for e: "))
print(iterationE(e))
```

Comment: The fromula is wrong. e^x = 1 + x + x^2/2! + x^3/3! + ... So e = 1 + 1/1 + 1/2! + 1/3! + 1/4! ... = 1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/6 + 1/24 + ...

Comment: Try again. Note, *do not* calculate the factorila at every iteration. Keep the value of the previous value of `den = 1/(i-1)!`.  Then, the current value of `1/i! = den/i`.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close.  I think this should work.  Basically, you needed to increment `num` in each loop cycle.

```
def iterationE(e):
    count = 1
    num = 1
    while count <= e:
        num += 1./count
        count = count + 1
    return num
e = int(input ("enter the number of iterations for e: "))
print(iterationE(e))
```

This is, by the way, what's known as the Harmonic Series, and it **does not** converge to `e`, and, in fact does not even converge.

I think a reasonable step would be first, though, to get this harmonic series to behave as you expect, and then work on the [Taylor Series expression for `e`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function#Formal_definition) as the next step.

Comment: This fails in the first iteration. When count = 0

Comment: Almost. You're off by one, this will give you div by zero error.

Comment: @Amadan, @karthikr: Yeah, when I switched the `count` and `num` lines I forgot to change count to `1`... for about 10 seconds, which was enough time for you both to downvote.  Very exciting for you, I'm sure.

Comment: Ok, now i just need to figure out how to add each iteration it gives up to the number I enter

Comment: @Rickjames59: I'm not sure what you mean in this comment.

Comment: say i enter 5.  the equation written out would be 1 + 1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5,   but the way it is it would give me 1 + 1/5

Comment: Rickjames59: Notice that @tom10 has `+=` in `num += 1/count` where you have `=`. Your version gives `1 + 1/5`; his version does not.